# Python regex returning None while parsing a requests response

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Requests to pull down a list of coin miner domains so I can add them to a firewall block list from:

'https://gitlab.com/ZeroDot1/CoinBlockerLists/blob/master/list_browser.txt?format=json&viewer=simple'

I would like to use regex to parse through the data and pull out just the domains

regex pattern:

```
match = re.compile(r'(\"\\\\u003e)(.*?)(\\\\u003c\/)')
```

sample data:
"""

lang=\"plaintext\"\u003echws.browsermine.com\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC322\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecieh.mx\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC323\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclgserv.pro\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC324\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclickandbuy.review\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC325\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclickandbuy.win\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC326\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclickwith.bi\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC327\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclickwith.bid\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC328\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclickwith.date\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC329\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecliggi.download\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC330\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003eclod.pw\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC331\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecloudcdn.gd\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC332\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecloudcdn.gdn\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC333\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecloudcoins.co\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC334\" class=\"line\" lang=\"plaintext\"\u003ecloudflane.com\u003c/span\u003e\n\u003cspan id=\"LC335\" class=\"line\"

"""

I started with trying to match the requests output as a string using

```
re.match(pattern, string)
re.search(pattern, string)
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

all of these return None or an empty list

It makes me think it's my regex, but when I use www.regex101.com it matches correctly. I originally had p = re.compile(r'(\"\\u003e)(.*?)(\\u003c/)'), without the escaped "/" at the end. I added  "/" so it would match in all types of regex, not just python regex.

I tried using response.content and changing the regex pattern match to bytes but it also returned None or an empty list for the byte strings.

I also tried to write the request response out to a file, then parse the file with my regex pattern, but that also returns None.

here is code I tried:

```
    import requests
    import pprint
    import re
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
    url = 'https://gitlab.com/ZeroDot1/CoinBlockerLists/blob/master/list_browser.txt?format=json&viewer=simple'
    #regex_pattern = re.compile(r'\\u003e(.*?)\\\\u003c/')
    p = re.compile(r'(\"\\\\u003e)(.*?)(\\\\u003c\/)')

    r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    data = r.text
    pprint.pprint(data)
    match = re.findall(p, data)
    print(match)
```

it looks like the format of my code is coming across very weird when I tried to paste it in "show some code" field. hopefully it makes sense

my end goal is to parse out just the domains by matching on group 2 of my regex.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try removing unnecessary groupings and backslashes: `p = re.compile(r'\u003e(.*?)\u003c')` or `p = re.compile(r'\\u003e(.*?)\\u003c')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You escaped your escape characters, and then escaped those, too!

`p = re.compile(r'(\"\\u003e)(.*?)(\\u003c\/)')` works just fine.

Also worth noting: if you ONLY want to capture domain names, and don't care about the first and last bits of the url, you can omit the capture groups around them and only get the results you care about. Additionally, from a quick look at the data, `\u003e` isn't unique (strings containing it don't necessarily have a domain name), but every url-containing string has the word "plaintext" before the domain name. Adding this looks like it filters the names properly.

`p = re.compile(r'plaintext\\"\\u003e(.*?)\\u003c\/')` - [Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/WeightyGrandWebpages)

Comment: Hey Nick,
Thank you for response!

the regex you provided does not capture the URLs, this is the output of the regex you provided:

"""
\n\u003cdiv class=\"file-content code js-syntax-highlight qa-file-content\"\u003e\n\u003cdiv class=\"line-numbers\"\u003e\n\u003ca class=\"diff-line-num\" data-line-number=\"1\" href=\"#L1\" id=\"L1\"\u003e\n\u003ci aria-hidden=\"true\" data-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-link\"\u003e

""

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize hitting enter would submit the comment.

Comment: No worries. I'm looking through the GitHub data now - I'll have an edited regex ready in a moment.
You can't add newlines in comments, but if you'd like to press enter without submitting, `Shift+Enter` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.